# Search on YouTube and return all links in Python

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, webdriver, webdriverwait

On YouTube, I want to search for certain videos (i.e. videos on Python) and after this, I want to return all videos this search returns. Right now if, I try this Python returns all the videos on the start page not on the page after the search.

Current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://youtube.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("search_query").send_keys("Python")
driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
links = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")
for x in links:
    print(x.get_attribute("href"))
```

What goes wrong here?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Your code looks fine.What's the error??

Comment: It is returning  after search results only right? What else do you want to return apart from that? I mean what is your question actually? What do you want to do?

Comment: Guys, he has clearly mentioned the requirement, and answers have already arrived. Please read the question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return all videos from the search with the keyword as **Python** you need to:

- Maximize the screen so all the resultant video links get rendered within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elements to be visible* before extracting the *href* attributes.
- You can use the following solution

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#search"))).send_keys("Python")
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.style-scope.ytd-searchbox#search-icon-legacy").click()
    print([my_href.get_attribute("href") for my_href in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.ytd-video-renderer#video-title")))])
    ```
  - Console Output:

    ```
    ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UeRnuGo-pg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cZsjOclmoM', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f79MRyMsjrQ', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtbckFw0pJs', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1Yd7upQsXY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLZuut1fYzQ', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ0IM_T4aio', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiSCMNBIP2g', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0lxfilGfak', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4mEzFDjqtA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3Ejdx6cIho', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8Tko2YC5hA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c3FXQU3TyCU', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE9v9rt6ziw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvHrNlAF0Y0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM']
    ```

Comment: how does maximizing the browser have anything to with it?

Answer (score 4):

But is better to use an explicit wait for this:

```
links = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "video-title")))
```

[Reference](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 3):

As per the discussion with @Mark:

It seems that the elements of the first page of Youtube are still in the DOM...

The only fix I see is to go to the search URL:

```
driver.get("http://youtube.com/results?search_query=Python")
# driver.find_element_by_name("search_query").send_keys("Python")
# driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
```

---

You should use WebDriverWait not sleep:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--incognito")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=opt)
driver.get("http://youtube.com")
driver.find_element_by_name("search_query").send_keys("Python")
driver.find_element_by_id("search-icon-legacy").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, "video-title")))
links = driver.find_elements_by_id("video-title")

for x in links:

    print(x.get_attribute("href"))
```

The output:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f79MRyMsjrQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLZuut1fYzQ
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N4mEzFDjqtA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1Yd7upQsXY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnDU1G9hWqU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cZsjOclmoM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3EbDbm8XqY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uCXIbkbDSE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJmcL1N2KQs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiSCMNBIP2g
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7lmCu8wz8ro
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25ovCm9jKfA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6Mc_sAPZ2Y
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yE9v9rt6ziw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8Tko2YC5hA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G0rQ7AEl5LA
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtbckFw0pJs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sugvnHA7ElY
```

Comment: But the first link in the output is not the first video you get when you search for python videos on youtube..? this is what I want

Comment: @MarkWekking are you looking for the ad URL?

Comment: No, I want the list of links to video's you get when you search for Python on youtube, in theory the first link should be: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfscVS0vtbw. because when you search for Python videos that is the first video it returns (https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Python)

Comment: @MarkWekking I found the problem... you need to add `--incognito` to `chrome_options` I'll add it to my answer... :)

Comment: This does not solve te problem for me .. I still get the video's that are on the youtube home screen and not the ones after the search term

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187999/discussion-between-moshe-slavin-and-mark-wekking).